# Interpreting Rudin 9.15

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Rudin 9.15 defines the function
$$
f( x, y ) = x^2 + y^2 - 2x^2 y - 4 \frac{x^6 y^2}{(x^4 + y^2)^2}
$$
for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$. One is then asked to prove that (a) $f$ is continuous, (b) all directional derivatives exist and vanish at the origin and the directional second derivatives are positive at the origin, YET (c) the origin is not a local minimum.

This question is not about proving those statements. It is about the implication of those statements.

My mental picture in 1D tells me that continuity of the function and vanishing of the first derivative and positive second derivative are enough for a local minimum. Is there a ‘mental picture’ way to explain why this is not true in more than one dimension? (Besides saying ‘I found a function where that is not true’)

Comment: The is probably some smooth path $\gamma:[-1,1]\to \mathbb R^2$ such that $\gamma(0)=0$ and $f(\gamma(t))$ has negative second derivative. Essentially, linear paths to zero are not enough to characterize the properties of a function - there are a lot of paths.

Comment: If the function was $g(x,y)=x^4+y^2-\dots$ rather than $x^2+y^2-\cdots$ it would be maybe easier to see.

Comment: "linear paths to zero are not enough to characterize the properties of a function" is a good mantra to live by

Comment: Let $y=x^2$ and look what happens in every neighborhood of the origin.

Answer (score 1):

You’ve already received the mantra in the comments, so let me now mention the correct generalization of the 1D theorems.

> **Theorem 1.**
>
> Let $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty open set, $f:U\to\Bbb{R}$ a function, and $p\in U$ a local minimum point for $f$. If $f$ is (Frechet-) differentiable at $p$, then $Df_p=0$. If in addition $f$ is twice (Frechet-) differentiable at $p$, then $D^2f_p$ is a positive-semidefinite bilinear form.

This is the analogue of $f’(p)=0$ and $f’’(p)\geq 0$ in the case $n=1$. We also have a partial converse, just like in 1D:

> **Theorem 2.**
>
> Let $U\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty open set, $f:U\to\Bbb{R}$ a function which is twice (Frechet-) differentiable at a point $p\in U$. If $Df_p=0$ and $D^2f_p$ is a strictly positive-definite bilinear form (i.e for all $h\in \Bbb{R}^n\setminus\{0\}$, $D^2f_p[h,h]>0$), then $p$ is a strict local minimum point for $f$.

This is the analogue of “$f’(p)=0$ and $f’’(p)>0$ implies $p$ is a strict local minimum point” in the case $n=1$.